# Nested port forwarding

Tags: networking, ftp, port, forwarding

This is first time I setup ftp server and I'm not really clever at network thing.

How do i want my connection to look like.

HOME > INTERNET > OFFICE_ROUTER > OFFICE_WORKSTATION > FTP_SERVER

OFFICE_WORKSTATION has 2 NIC: connection to FTP_SERVER and internet connection by OFFICE_ROUTER, FTP_SERVER has only connetion to OFFICE_WORKSTATION (localNetwork)

What I already did is vsftpd on FTP_SERVER with tls and it's already accesible from localNetwork - OFFICE_WORKSTATION (e.g by using totalCommander > 10.10.10.10:21)

I did port and ip forwarding on OFFICE_ROUTER (let's say its public ip is 192.192.192.1 and local 192.168.10.1)
So when I connect from HOME to OFFICE_ROUTER it sends me further to OFFICE_WORKSTATION.
Then i setup netsh on OFFICE_WORKSTATION ( localNetwork ip 10.10.10.50, inernetNetwork ip 192.168.10.10) to get 192.168.10.10:21 from internet and send it to 10.10.10.10:21 which is my FTP_SERVER. But such setup gives me "500 illegal PORT command"

Maybe it's because FTP_SERVER don't know how to send data back ? Because now it should respond from 10.10.10.10:21 (FTP_SERVER) to 10.10.10:50  OFFICE_WORKSTATION) and here netsh should take care of it and output it to OFFICE_ROUTER

I already know that ftp uses two ports data and command. Maybe i shoud forward both ports ?
I did test where my OFFICE_WORKSTATION serve FTP and I was able to connect it by HOME station by using single portForwarding on OFFICE_ROUTER.

With totalCommander from OFFICE_WORKSTATION i connect to 10.10.10.10:21 and it works, but if i try (also from OFFICE_WORKSTATION) in totalCommander to use those configured ports ( 192.168.10.10:21 > 10.10.10.10:21 ) I've got same error "500 illegal PORT command"
I want my OFFICE_WORKSTATION to serve as portForwarding (i don't even know how to call it). So at the end I think problem lies in error/problem in portForwarding configuration.

I would be very pleased if someone could give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

> This is first time I setup ftp server

Don't.

Please, do not use FTP. You really, **really** do not want to use FTP. We do not want you to use FTP. [Vint Cerf](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/07/internet_inception_security_vint_cerf_google_hangout/) does not want you to use FTP. [Bill Gates](https://news.microsoft.com/2012/01/11/memo-from-bill-gates/) does not want you to use FTP. Even FTPS (which I'm guessing is what you are trying to say).

There are few things worse than FTP. FTPS is one of them. Setting up FTPS with *any* sort of NAT is *really* difficult for an expert systems admin.

There are lots of better solutions - SFTP (note order of letters - it's completely different) for one.

Comment: Huge thanks for that. For sure you're right about security. I'am also aware of difference in ftps and sftp, but leaving that for a moment , and just for learning purposes apart from ftp could you elaborate a bit on such scenario ? Or just give me some keywords to read about . Thanks in advance.